# Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute after updating Snowpack

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, package.json, svelte, snowpack

I'm new to Snowpack. After updating it some of my resources are blocked:

```sh
@snowpack/plugin-svelte            ^3.5.2  →  ^3.6.0     
@snowpack/web-test-runner-plugin   ^0.2.1  →  ^0.2.2     
snowpack                          ^3.0.13  →  ^3.1.2
```

I'm getting the following browser error:

**Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource** 'http://localhost:8080/_snowpack/hmr-client.js' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'oBiRohK77Pj8AolnFKZapB/LahnUq2CVH18sxk4filI='. The resource has been blocked.

If I clean cache now everything works as expected. But If I close tab or full browser and launch again with `npm start` or accessing to my local server the blocking error appears again.

This is my package JSON:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "snowpack dev",
    "build": "snowpack build",
    "test": "web-test-runner \"src/**/*.test.js\""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@snowpack/plugin-dotenv": "^2.0.5",
    "@snowpack/plugin-svelte": "^3.6.0",
    "@snowpack/web-test-runner-plugin": "^0.2.2",
    "@testing-library/svelte": "^3.0.3",
    "@web/test-runner": "^0.12.17",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "smart-webcomponents": "^9.1.0",
    "snowpack": "^3.1.2",
    "svelte": "^3.35.0",
    "svelte-chartjs": "^1.0.1",
    "svelte-i18n": "^3.3.7"
  }
```

Should I add any config to my `snowpack dev` in this new release?
Any idea would be really appreciated.